# The type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, visual-studio-2013

Despite the references being present already, or a default part of the build process, i'm
getting

**Error 1** The type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

**Error 2** The type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

**Error 3** The type 'System.Linq.IQueryProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

on `Divisions` variable name.

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Division> Divisions
{
   get
     {
         return this.GetTable<Division>();
     }
}
```

This happened after i reinstalled visual studio 2013 express for web. projects that compiled and had no error previously, are all doing this exact same error. can't add the reference it asks for because it's already included in the build schedule. tried removing the table reference and re-adding through the `DBML` auto generated code, and initially seems to work... but then the next table down the list is affected, and the next and so on. if i remove them all and re-add them all, the problem starts over again.

my web.config is littered with flailing attempts to kill this error. i've tried recreating the project from scratch, same thing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="GenesisConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Genesis;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off">         
</customErrors>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true"/>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="cshtm-Integrated-4.0"/>
        <remove name="cshtml-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
           System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
           Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="cshtml-Integrated-4.0" path="*.cshtml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
        <add name="cshtm-Integrated-4.0" path="*.cshtm" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>

</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Is this an instance of broken VS release, or what am i missing? did i start the project wrong, and i forgot to say `klaatu verata nicto`? i'd post a stack trace if it would even finish building the application. thanks ahead for your help!

Comment: Your project doesn't reference System.Core, or the reference has been damaged.  Fix that.

Comment: what does `klaatu verata nicto` mean?

Comment: Klaatu verata nikto is from "the day the earth stood still" and "army of darkness" two classics. recommended. that line was intended as a joke and doesn't have anything to do with the actual issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's System.Core.dll indeed, check the official msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ok. i've tried to add that reference. doesn't like it. says "A reference to 'System.Core' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system." so... got any tricks for referencing it anyway?

Comment: Add a line to the csproj file telling it to <Reference Include="System.Core" />